# I get weird notification of software update in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, virus, firefox-3.6

Which ever site I visit I get this notification in Firefox

**FireFox prevented this site(sitename.com) from asking you to install software on your computer.**

And then I get a red bar below it which says

**SYSTEM UPDATE REQUIRED - A critical software update is needed for your browser. Click allow to update now.**

Here's a screen shot

[image]

I am not sure what's wrong? Is it a viral infection or maybe my Firefox has gone bad ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Add-ons do you have an add on called Game Play Labs? Uninstall this and the red banner should dissapear.

Comment: Thank a lot for your quick response, I thought it was some kind of virus. You are genius : ) How did you come to know there was a add-on of Game Play Labs? I think my brother had installed it.

Comment: it might be possible that Game Play Labs addon might not be confirming to some standards set by firefox 4 .   
@Searock : try uninstalling addons one by one to see which addon is causing trouble

Comment: @Searock I have came across this before, Im glad this has helped :).